# Please feature this meta post

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

My first could describe a call or a fell, in two ways,
And it sounds like a way of going fast in olden times.

My second could describe a paper or a cloud, in two ways,
And docked it's almost my first, but not in truth.

My whole is used to know what's important,
Like for instance a featured SE post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an incomplete answer.  I think the word may be:

> Highlight

My first could describe a call or a fell, in two ways,
And it sounds like a way of going fast in olden times.

> *High* - You can describe a phone call as just saying hi (high).  You can describe someone's fall or a tree [fell](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fell) as being high.  As @humn stated, [Hie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hie) could be a term for going fast in olden times.
>
>  **OP edit:** the adjective "high" can mean high-pitched (as a call/shout can be) or high altitude (as a fell/mountain can be).

My second could describe a paper or a cloud, in two ways,
And docked it's almost my first, but not in truth.

> *Light*  You can describe paper and cloud as being light (lightweight).  A cloud is visible because of sun*light* scattering particles through tiny droplets the atmosphere.
>
>  **OP edit:** the adjective "light" can mean light-coloured (like white paper and white clouds) or lightweight (again like paper and clouds which don't weigh much).

My whole is used to know what's important,
Like for instance a featured SE post.

> Highlight means to emphasize or make prominent.  You could say that a featured post is highlighted to get more views.

At time of posting, the current featured post is amusingly:

> [image]

Comment: Oh nice!  I was looking for a word like that.  I still have no clue for the "And docked..." line.

Comment: Correct answer! But you need to work on the explanations for lines 1-2, 4, and the "in two ways" in 3. Also there's a double meaning of the last line, although it's more of an easter egg than really necessary for the puzzle.

Comment: Line 2 now solved thanks to @humn. Note that it says "a fell" not "a fall". For the double meaning of the last line, look at the *currently* featured posts :-)

Comment: I could use a hint... Or help from the exchange to figure out line 4.

Comment: For line 4, think of cryptic crosswords for help interpreting "docked". For lines 1 and 3, "in two ways" refers to two different (adjectival) meanings of the relevant word - what can it be used to describe?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Could you edit another hint into the question?  I'm unable to come up with an answer.

Comment: I edited in some explanations. For "docked", try removing a letter.

Comment: Did you mean rot13(YVTUG 'qbpxrq' vf VTU juvpu vf yvxr UVTU ohg abg dhvgr)?

Comment: That sure sounds right to me.  @Randal'Thor?

Comment: Pretty much. I was thinking to remove just the last letter, not the first and last as @Graylocke suggests, because the result is almost *[first part of answer]* but sounds like "lie".